IntelliJ IDEA: Load Maven Project fails with "java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe"
Intellij Idea successfully recognized that the opened project was a Maven Project and showed a pop-up with the button Load Maven Project, but after clicking on the button - nothing happened on the UI.

I have checked the Intellij Idea log file and found a multiple errors logs like this:

2024-09-23 21:28:20,439 [1325080]   INFO - #o.j.i.maven - Using
extension org.jetbrains.idea.maven.maven3.Maven3Support@59e87873 to
start MavenServer 2024-09-23 21:28:20,451 [1325092]   INFO -
#o.j.i.maven - Sent token to maven server 2024-09-23 21:28:20,711 [1325352]   WARN - #c.i.e.r.RemoteProcessSupport - The cook failed to
start due to java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe 2024-09-23
21:28:20,753 [1325394]   INFO - #c.i.e.r.RemoteProcessSupport -
Terminating: 127.0.0.1:61362/Maven36ServerImpl3157b954 2024-09-23
21:28:20,753 [1325394]   INFO - STDERR - Exception in thread
"DefaultDispatcher-worker-14"
org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.CannotStartServerException:
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.rmi.ConnectIOException:
error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is:
2024-09-23 21:28:20,753 [1325394]   INFO - STDERR -
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe

seems like those errors were thrown exactly when I clicked the Load Maven Project Button
Any ideas on how to fix it?
My environment is the following:

IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.2 (Ultimate Edition)
javac 21.0.4
Apache Maven 3.8.5
Apple M2 Pro
MacOS Sequoia


Was that project using Maven 4?

Perhaps you should post the POM.

Do you use ESET antivirus on your Mac? Does it help if you uninstall it? If it's not related to ESET, try adding the following in Help | Edit Custom VM Options and in Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Importing | VM options for importer: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true. Then restart the IDE.

@BasilBourque, for example, I tried to import the following project: https://github.com/BuntyRaghani/spring-boot-hello-world and the issue is the same: CannotStartServerException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is:
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe

@CrazyCoder, correct, I am using ESET on my mac.

Why using an old Maven version? (current version 3.9.9)...

The issue is caused by ESET. We've received multiple reports of the "Broken pipe" error caused by it when the IDE tries to use localhost for IPC.
This is incorrect behavior of ESET, it should not block local resources. Please contact ESET support for the solution. Disable/uninstall ESET as a workaround.

After disabling the ESET firewall the issue disappeared
